# Redundant output when analysing txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text

I wrote a simple program that analyses .txt files in Python.

The function I build for analyzing 'how often certain words can be found for an input text file' additions short words that are part of larger words, e.g ('not', 'note') so that the result isn't correct.

```
def apply_all(self):
    with open(self.fname, 'r') as f:
        words = f.read()
        filtered = "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in '".,;:!?–-', words))
        word = []
        word_list = []
        for i in filtered.split():
            word.append(i)
            word_list.append(words.count(i))
        b = dict(zip(word, word_list))
        aux = [(b[key], key) for key in b]
        aux.sort()
        aux.reverse()
    print('Pairs', aux)
```

Is there any simple solution to this problem, or do I have to correct the output via multiple queries?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  In order to write a good question, you should include the following information: ① What you tried, ② What you expected to observe, ③ What you observed instead.  As it stands, your current question seems to belong rather to a code review site.

Comment: @Alfe Thanks for pointing that out. I'll learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation `words.count(i)` returns the number of occurrences of a substring and therefore will count both `not` and `note` when `i=not`. The easiest way to fix this, without deviating too much from your original code, is to split the input and call `count` on the resulting list called `individual_words`.

Please note that I have converted the text input to lowercase otherwise `The` and `the` are counted as single occurrences.

```
words = "The not so quick brown dog jumps over the lazy dog eating his bone"
filtered = "".join(filter(lambda x: x not in '".,;:!?–-', words)).lower()
word = []
word_list = []
individual_words = filtered.split()
for i in individual_words:
    word.append(i)    
    word_list.append(individual_words.count(i))
b = dict(zip(word, word_list))
aux = [(b[key], key) for key in b]
aux.sort()
aux.reverse()
print('Pairs', aux)
```

This gives the following output:

```
Pairs [(2, 'the'), (2, 'dog'), (1, 'so'), (1, 'quick'), (1, 'over'), (1, 'not'), (1, 'lazy'), (1, 'jumps'), (1, 'his'), (1, 'eating'), (1, 'brown'), (1, 'bone')]
```